# Error warning in bottom right corner not showing with Firebug

Tags: javascript, firebug

For some reason firebug is not showing that litte red 'X' icon in the bottom right corner anymore in my localhost development.

Is there a setting that I might have somehow changed?

I purposely make an error in my .js file and I get nothing!

Answer (score 1):

In Firebug, click the dropdown next to the "Console" tab, and check "Enable console for Local Files".

Comment: "Local files" are just if you run a html directly from your disk. I think when he sais "localhost development", he is running through `http://localhost`, which is not considered "Local files" in this context (even though it physically is...)

Answer (score 1):

Many asynchronous callbacks "swallow" errors. That is, any error can occur in the callback and it won't show in Firebug or any just-in-time debugger I know of. However, with "Break on All Errors" on, Firebug will stop. Look for that in the Script tab options.

Are you using TrimPath? It can also "swallow" errors.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I have no idea.  But I have run into firebug issues before and reinstalling takes about 2 minutes and usually fixes the problem

Answer (score 0):

Do you have anything like this in your javascript?

```
window.onerror = function(){
    return true;
};
```

This will suppress any normal behavior of errors.

Answer (score 0):

Is the Firebug icon yellow or grey? If it is grey, then Firebug is turned off (or all the panels are disabled).